# How To Delete All Files of A Certain size in Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, size, del

I currently can delete all .gz files with this command:

```
del type f -name "*.gz"
```

I tried to delete all files below 2kb using this, but it still deletes all .gz files:

```
del type f -name "*.gz" size -2k
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use PowerShell for this?

gci -Path c:\temp*.gz -Recurse | ? {$_.Length -lt 2KB}

You can then pipe that to remove-item

gci -Path c:\temp*.gz -Recurse | ? {$_.Length -lt 2KB} | rm